# Ant Script to find substring

Tags: ant

How to write ant script to get a substring from one property file and copy in another property file?
For Eg. I am getting oracle_12c in a property file but now I want to store oracle in one value and 12c in another value in a property file.Can anyone suggest how to write antscript for this.